# How to design an artificial neural network for speaker recognition application?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I want to design a speaker recognition software that uses artificial neural networks (given an audio sound, i want to be able to identify who the speaker is).
I was thinking of storing the names of the speakers inside a database where each speaker has a unique id:

`id`  `first_name` `last_name`

The network is designed as such: 
- the input are the audio characteristics (frequency,pitch,etc...)
- hidden layers
- a single output: the database ID of the speaker

My question is whether the logic behind the network architecture is valid or not. Is it correct to have the output of the network a database ID (where I normalize over the maximum ID found?

I thought about having multiple outputs where each output corresponds to a certain speaker. But as the number of speakers increase, the number of outputs will increase with them , so if I have 10 000 speakers, I will have to have 10,000 outputs which I deemed unreasonable.

Is this the proper way to tackle such a problem using ANN?

Comment: Doesn't sound completely unreasonable to me (except for the ID, that's not very robust). However, you picked yourself a hard task and as such you should research as much papers about this topic as you can. Find out how other people did it and what worked best.

Comment: This question better be asked at [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com). And more details are needed. In short - database id almost certainly won't work. You problem is not trivial and you may need lot of work/reseach to do it right. I would try one neuron per speaker with softmax activation first or maybe hierarchical softmax if computational speed is issue. 10000 classes is a lot but not too much if you have enough training samples per class and fast CPU.

Comment: A full answer is beyond the scope here.  In general, neural networks are intuitively a good fit for this problem because our brains perform this task.  What we lack is a detailed understanding of the full pathway from the auditory canal through the speech centers.  (In this case, the front ends are more important, which is where we have more knowledge.)  You should look these things:  1, NN architectures dealing with sound or massively time-serial inputs.  2, known speech features, e.g., pitch/formants, 3, human auditory and associated neural models (which you've done in part.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is whether the logic behind the network architecture is valid or not. Is it correct to have the output of the network a database ID (where I normalize over the maximum ID found?

This is wrong way. If you treat outputs as numbers you'll impose some kind of closeness on a person, that some persons (those with closer `id`s) have more similar speech than those with more distant `id`s, so some mistakes are penalized more than others.

> I thought about having multiple outputs where each output corresponds
>   to a certain speaker. But as the number of speakers increase, the
>   number of outputs will increase with them , so if I have 10 000
>   speakers, I will have to have 10,000 outputs which I deemed
>   unreasonable.

Unfortunately, this is the right way. Usually, a [softmax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) output unit is used then multiclass classification is performed. This way you do not impose any preference, and all mistakes are penalized independent of proximity of the identifiers.

Actually, the problem you're trying to solve is very hard (from my point of view). I doubt even a human could differentiate 10,000 speakers! You'll need lots of speech data for each speaker, some smart preprocessing, and even more smarter machine (most likely, deep) learning algorithms to make it work. Don't think that you can just throw in an Artificial Neural Network, and it'd *just work*. There are many types of ANNs, and we still don't know how to train them reliably in the general case.